# displaying images in a tableview cell similar to facebook or pinterest

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, uiimageview

I'm working on an app that has a list of conversations and in those conversations can be one or more images. I'm looking to have it look similar to how facebook does it where it's in a grid-like format that grows or shrinks images based on the amount present with the option to click on the one with an overlay for conversations with a large amount of images.

here's a basic idea of what I'm trying to do

[image: rough idea]

searching around the closest I found to what I want is [this](https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/master/ios9/CollectionView) but the example is rather crude and just does simple text, I need to be able to do images and handle setting up an overlay with a counter.

Comment: You want to show different photos(with different size) by collectionView, right?

Comment: yes, the idea would be it'd hold up to 5 images and the fifth image would have a click action that'd open a dialog to show the entire list, much like facebook does.

Answer (score 1):

Just some idea about how to achieve that, let's take the [third view in the sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/ios-samples/ios9-collectionview/) as an example, in your collectionView, you should have a property called `isExpand` to check if you need to expand the images or not:

```
public bool isExpand {get; set;}
```

And then in the itemSource:

```
public override nint GetItemsCount (UICollectionView collectionView, nint section)
{
    // Return the number of items

    if (isExpand)
    {
        return Numbers.Count;
    }
    else {
        return Numbers.Count > 5 ? 5: Numbers.Count;
    }

}
```

In the `GetCell` :

```
public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell (UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    // Get a reusable cell and set it's title from the item
    var cell = collectionView.DequeueReusableCell ("Cell", indexPath) as TextCollectionViewCell;
    cell.Title = Numbers [(int)indexPath.Item].ToString();

    if (!isExpand)
    {
        //add the button on the fifth image or an image with button icon
        if (indexPath.Row == 4)
        {

        }
    }
    else
    {
        //remove the button on the fifth image
    }

    return cell;
}
```

And in the `itemSelected` or `button click action`:

```
public override void ItemSelected(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    if (isExpand)
    {
        // reload the dataSoure with all the images
    }
    else {
        // handle the click action on the fifth image
        if (indexPath.Row == 4)
        {
            // reload the dataSoure with 5 images

        }
    }
}
```